# Remove the first N rows from each factor level in an r data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, greatest-n-per-group

With the `dat` below. How can I make a new dataframe subset that includes all values except the first five rows for each IndID? Said differently I want new data frame with the first 5 rows for each IndID excluded.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), each  = 10),
                  Number = sample(1:100,40))
```

I have seen a number of SO posts that select data, but I am not sure how to remove as mentioned above.

Comment: I think there's still a simpler way in base, but so far, `dat[ave(rep(TRUE, nrow(dat)), dat$IndID, FUN = function(x){cumsum(x) > 5}),]`

Comment: this seems simple with `data.table`... `setDT(dat)[, .SD[1:5], by = IndID]`

Comment: Or something like `dat[-Reduce(function(x,y) c(x,y:(y+4)), init=c(), match(unique(dat$IndID), dat$IndID)), ]` if your data is sorted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`'s `slice()` functionality:

```
dat %>% 
    group_by(IndID) %>% 
    slice(6:n())
```

Comment: or `slice(-1:-5)`, if you like

Answer (score 7):

In base R, `tapply()` is handy when used on a sequence of row numbers with `tail()`.

```
idx <- unlist(tapply(1:nrow(dat), dat$IndID, tail, -5))
dat[idx, ]
```

Note that this will be more efficient with `use.names=FALSE` in `unlist()`.

With *data.table*, you can do the following with `tail()`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[dat[, tail(.I, -5), by=IndID]$V1]
```

Comment: Seems about an order of magnitude faster than using `.SD[-(1:5)]`

Answer (score 6):

If the data is sorted and you are guaranteed to have at least `n` rows per group...

```
n = 5
w = match(unique(dat$IndID), dat$IndID)
dat[- (rep(w, each = n) + 1:n - 1L), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` of base `R` to split `dat` by `IndID`, remove first 5 rows of each sub-group, and then `rbind` it after that.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat,as.character(dat$IndID)), function(x) x[-(1:5),]))
```